# select2 rails dropdown not rendering properly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I was able to get select2-rails working for the most part, but when I click on the search bar I get the following:

[image: Select2 not working on search bar]

I am using the following CoffeeScript:

```
    $('#query').select2({
            placeholder: placeholder_text
            minimumInputLength: 2
            ajax:
                    url: end_point
                    tags: "false",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 200,
                    cache: true,
                    data: (params) ->
                            return { search: params.term.toUpperCase() }
                    processResults: (data, params) ->
                            return { results: data }
            theme: "bootstrap"
    })
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
   <form>
      <%= select_tag "search", {}, id: "query" %>
    </form>
</div>
```

application.css

```
 *= require select2                                                                                 
 *= require select2-bootstrap                                                                       
 *= require_tree .                                                                                  
 *= require_self
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery                                                                                  
//= require jquery.turbolinks                                                                       
//= require jquery_ujs                                                                              
//= require bootstrap                                                                               
//= require turbolinks                                                                              
//= require select2                                                                                 
//= require_tree .
```

As I said, I can query fine, I just want the search bar to align correctly...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the js console?

Comment: What does your CoffeeScript really look like? The indentation in your question seems to be a bit off.

Comment: The alignment is just a css problem.  Mine was due to bootstrap loading in the wrong order of the select2 stuff.  Since I use bootstrap-sass, that I have a css.scss file that loads first and does the import for bootstrap and sprockets.  After that selects looks just fine.

Answer (score 5):

This is an expansion of trh comment as it was what put me on the correct path.

When using select2 with bootstrap this code located in assets/stylesheets/application.scss fixed everything for me

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";
```

Comment: This is what I figured to do as well but now I'm seeing this error. `File to import not found or unreadable: select2.` Did you happen to see this at first?

Comment: Hello,  I do not think i received that error. Ensure you have gem 'sass-rails' and all other requirements for select2 + bootstrap. If all else fails re install gems.